# YouTube Api V3 - Videos.update - Forbidden error

Tags: javascript, node.js, youtube-api

I'm trying to update video's description using Youtube API, but I'm just getting Forbidden Error.

Videos.insert call is actually working, the authentication is being done on the same way for both (as I show on code). But for Videos.update it just doesn't work.
I'm not trying to do these two operations at once, it's just to explain better the situation and make the code shorter to read.

```
const Youtube = require('youtube-api');
const request = require('request');

// test variables below
const accessToken = 'ASPODKODASP';
const title = 'test';
const description ='test';
const url = 'https://testvideo.url/sadokdas.mp4';
const youtubeId = 'm_23k21423';

Youtube.authenticate({
  type: 'oauth',
  access_token: accessToken
});

Youtube.videos.insert({
  resource: {
    snippet: {
      title: title,
      description: description
    },
    status: {
      privacyStatus: 'public'
    }
  },
  part: 'snippet, status',
  media: {
    body: request(url)
  }
}); // <- THIS WORKS

Youtube.videos.update({
  id: youtubeId,
  snippet: {
    title: title,
    description: description,
    categoryId: '22'
  },
  part: 'snippet'
}, (err, data) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log('error on updating youtube description');
    console.log(err);

    return;
  }
});
```

I expected the video description to get updated but instead I'm getting

```
code: 403,
errors: 
[ { domain: 'youtube.video',
reason: 'forbidden',
message: 'Forbidden' } ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You want to update a video of YouTube using "youtube-api" of Node.js.
- You have already been able to insert new video using your script.

  - In your environment, you have already been able to use YouTube Data API.
- In your script, an error occurs at `Youtube.videos.update()`.

If my understanding is correct, how about this modification? In this modification, the request body of `Youtube.videos.update()` was modified.

#### Modified script:

From:

```
Youtube.videos.update({
  id: youtubeId,
  snippet: {
    title: title,
    description: description,
    categoryId: '22'
  },
  part: 'snippet'
}, (err, data) => {
```

To:

```
Youtube.videos.update({
  resource: { // Added
    id: youtubeId,
    snippet: {
      title: title,
      description: description,
      categoryId: '22'
    }
  },
  part: 'snippet'
}, (err, data) => {
```

#### References:

- [Videos: update](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/update?hl=en)
- [youtube-api](https://github.com/IonicaBizau/youtube-api)

If I misunderstood your question, I apologize.

Comment: You nailed it, I looked to this code a lot of time, not sure how I didn't realize I was missing the resource. Thanks for your help bro. Best

Comment: @LuizAsFight Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. At googleapis of Node.js for using Google APIs, the request body is set to the property of ``resource``. So I could confirm that the same request body can be used at "youtube-api".